# AngularJS wait for HTTP event to success

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am devolping a website using ionic framework.This is my code:

```
  $rootScope.$on('$cordovaPush:tokenReceived', function(event, data) {
          storageService.save("deviceToken", data.token);
        });

 var devicetoken =JSON.parse(storageService.get("deviceToken")); 

    HomeOwners.Create(devicetoken).then(function(response) {
        console.log(response.user_id);
    })
alert(devicetoken);
```

But this alert null.When I refresh page the i t alret me device token value.

Please Help

Comment: could you add `storageService` code?

Answer (score 2):

The HTTP request is an asynchronous process, which is worked on in the backgroud. So when you do `alert(devicetoken)` the request is most likely not done.

By changing the code as little as possible you could call a function inside the `$cordovaPush:tokenReceived` catch.

```
$rootScope.$on('$cordovaPush:tokenReceived', function(event, data) {

    storageService.save("deviceToken", data.token);

    weHaveTheDataDoSomething();

});
```

Since you also tagged this with AngularJS you should probably read a little about resolves and asynchronous processes. One example of resolves: [Resolving Data the Right Way](http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/data-the-right-way/)

Answer (score 0):

The point is to wait for the request to finish before trying to access or get any response.

Try this:

```
var devicetoken;
storageService.get('deviceToken')
 .success(function(response){
    devicetoken = angular.fromJson(response);
    console.log(devicetoken);
}).error(function(response){
  // do something on error with response
});
```

If this doesn't work, please post the `storageService` code.